# Tables within the Reclassify tool- what is it, where is it?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, excel, reclassify, table

ArcMap 10.1 here. I have a raster set I'm looking to reclassify. The field I need to re-classify is currently a string of words like "Thing 1" and "Thing 2" and I'm going to set them to be 1 and 2.

I understand that you can create essentially a table within the reclassify tool, save it, and then use it again in another operation. What type of file is this, and where is it found? I can't find it in windows explorer, but it does show up in arc catalog.

Reason is, I have an excel sheet where all of my "Thing 1"s are matched up with the number I want. Let's assume there are thousands of "Thing 1"s and renumbering them within the reclass window would be impractical.

Is there a way to 
(A) edit a reclass table within excel 
(b) have arcmap reclass tool read in my excel, dbf, csv, or some other kind of file?

Thanks for thoughts, suggestions

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The File type of the table is "Info Table" .You can add the table in ArcMap => Right click to the table => Data => Export = > Export your Info table to the Text File.
 Import the text file to Excel :

1. Open Microsoft Excel
2. Select Data tab
3. Click From Text
4. Import your Text File then save the Excel.
   change your reclassify then import the Excel to Arcmap and export to Info Table.

Another option is use of Xtools pro to export the Info table to Excel.It's better than the first method because if it's maintain all of the Languages and Characters from Info Table to xls Format.

Comment: Thank you wetland- that is exactly the answer I needed. The trick is having arcmap save the excel to an info file.